# What are the next steps after installing mapnik with vcpkg to see mapnik usage

Tags: c++, vcpkg, mapnik

I installed vcpkg and followed the instructions mentioned in [this](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/blob/master/INSTALL.md) to install mapnik using vcpkg.

Basically, I did `vcpkg install mapnik`. It installed a lot of packages and supporting libraries like boost, libmapnik. Now it has created a libmapnik.dll inside `C:\src\vcpkg\packages\mapnik_x86-windows\bin` and also a lib file libmapnik.lib under `C:\src\vcpkg\packages\mapnik_x86-windows\lib`

What are the next steps after that? How do I use this? Do I need to write C++ code to use it? If yes, do we have any sample code to run and actually see mapnik in use?

I would like to import a shape file I have, to mapnik and see how it renders the map.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write C++ code to use it (see [this](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/LearningMapnik)). Most users just use it with Python (python-mapnik) or Node JS (node-mapnik) bindings which require mapnik as a base dependency. If you just want to visualize the shapefile with mapnik, you can check out either [Tilemill](https://github.com/tilemill-project/tilemill) or [Kosmtik](https://github.com/kosmtik/kosmtik) that uses node-mapnik. On Windows, these applications may be easier to use with Docker or WSL, as there are no prebuilt binaries for node-mapnik on Windows at the moment, and you will likely run into difficulty trying to build it yourself. However, if you really want to use mapnik with C++, you can see the [demo](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/tree/master/demo/c%2B%2B) in the main repo.